# What should the design of our site be?

Tags: discussion, site-design

<sub>Part of the *[7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta(http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/)*]</sub>

We have our site here, and we should start thinking about the theme. We don't *have* to create a full theme, but if we can get some outstanding ideas, it will only make our site better. **What are some ideas that you can think of?** We should try to get *some* ideas.

Comment: This is a great question... however, sites don't get their design until they get out of beta (i.e. they are a graduated site). So don't delete the question, but keep in mind it may keep years for this design to happen.

Comment: @hichris123 I know it takes a while for the design, but it *was* in the 7 essential questions of every beta. If they put it in there, it must be somewhat important.

Comment: The 7 essential questions are kinda out of date... if you're bored there's some [mSO questions on this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/201776/could-we-update-the-7-essential-meta-questions-blog-post-or-not-link-it-promi).

Comment: @hichris123 Ouch... 4 years old, not updated, nor taken down? Whoops! Oh well it can spark some activity because lately the site has been slowing down...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an event years into the future. Also, as the 7 essential questions are no longer relevant at such an early stage.

Comment: A relevant post (on this meta) by one of our designers from earlier this week: [Custom Arduino Community design and logo - Information gathering](https://arduino.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2716/80022) :)

Answer (score 1):

Just a few ideas I had:

- Arduino color (HEX: `00979c`, accent color: `e34c00`) We may have to get it cleared by Arduino itself, but SE is pretty well respected so I don't think that it will be *that* hard as long as we try to add a few key differences. The colors, however, are comforting for a user to see.
- An Uno with a LED (blinking, maybe?). This is a symbolic "start" of Arduino knowledge, and might be a good symbol too new users. Animations might be annoying, maybe just two quick flashes at a page load? It might still be distracting but at least have the LED drawn on.

We should also think of names for the site... oh well, tomorrow!

I make a small little image here in GIMP:

[image: Example Diagram]

Comment: Take a look at [gaming.se] site theme. Its got some elements of what you suggest.

Comment: If we were to have an LED blink on page load, it most definitely should be the on-board pin 13 LED.

Comment: @Guy Good point. However, I'm not going to mess with the design: it is still a bit off. We only got into public today.