# New site design launched

Tags: discussion, site-design

As you can see, the new site design just went live! At this point, we are done with major revisions to the design (although you can still report CSS/styling bugs by starting a new post and tagging it with [site-design](/questions/tagged/site-design) and [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)). Thank you for your valuable design feedback.

I have enjoyed working with you to create this theme. Thank you for being engaged in the process, and I hope you enjoy the new design!

Comment: I browse pages of the site to enjoy the new design. :-). thank you.

Comment: I very like the light teal for visited links

Comment: Really appreciate your words @Juraj. I'm glad you like it :)

Comment: Very nice, thank you @paintedbicycle! Thank you for your efforts.

Comment: 3 LEDs at the very bottom of pages

Answer (score 4):

even the 404 page is customized :-)

[image]

Comment: Cool! Amazing attention to detail!